# Wordpress Theme on Contribution pages

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress, theme

I am having an issue with setting what theme/layout is being used on contribution pages. I assume it is using the defualt layout but that ends up allowing sidebars and a slider to display. how do i set the layout for civicrm pages and profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're adding the Civi content via a WP page (Pages > Add Page, use the CiviCRM button to add your chosen functionality), under Page Attributes there should be the option to select a template.  Depending on the theme you've selected, there may be a Full Width option.  If not, you may be able to add that option to your theme.

~ Lesley