# Live contribution pages coming up blank

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

I've recently updated our CiviCRM install to v4.7.9 (was 4.7.6 IIRC). Now it seems our contribution pages aren't filling with anything -- the theme parts show, but the main part of the page is empty:
[image: empty contribution page]
I've looked at the page source, and can see that various CiviCRM script links are in there, but there's no sign of the contribution form fields. Is there something I need to reset to get the fields back, or have I got a bigger problem...?

Versions: Wordpress 4.5.3, Twenty Fourteen theme, CiviCRM 4.7.9

**Edit:** Looks like profile pages are doing the same thing. It's all working in Test Drive/Preview, but not on "live" pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a few questions on this site relating to:

- CiviCRM not displaying pages under certain WordPress themes, or
- CiviCRM showing only CiviCRM content - without the theme!

In particular I'd recommend [checking out this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8475/the-contribution-payment-verification-page-has-lost-the-site-theme-styling) which, while it describes different symptoms to what you're reporting, may help point you in the right direction.

There is also a question on [which WordPress themes are thought to work well](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/best-wordpress-theme-framework-for-correct-display-of-civicrm).

My suggestion would be to try other "stock" WordPress themes first, and see if the page contents start appearing. If so, then you have a good reference point to analyse the problem. If not, then you might be looking at a CiviCRM bug.

Twenty Fourteen theme is a "core" (if older?) Wordpress theme that CiviCRM is likely to have been tested with. Other WordPress plugins might be a factor still, so if you have the same issue with all themes then look into the possibility that a plugin is interfering.

Some other questions which seem similar or related to issues with CiviCRM in WordPress themes:

- [The contribution payment verification page has lost the site theme styling](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8475/the-contribution-payment-verification-page-has-lost-the-site-theme-styling)
- [Why does CiviCRM render a validation failure without the Wordpress theme?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/why-does-civicrm-render-a-validation-failure-without-the-wordpress-theme)
- [CiviMail Unsubscribe link goes to an empty Wordpress page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/civimail-unsubscribe-link-goes-to-an-empty-wordpress-page)
- [Wordpress Theme on Contribution pages](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8573/wordpress-theme-on-contribution-pages) (maybe)

Comment: If you track down the issues you're having, please consider filing an issue in the [CiviCRM bug tracker](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/issues/). I suspect there's a bug happening here which is affecting a number of sites, but has lacked anyone taking the time to track it down. If you engage a developer to  solve this problem, consider asking them to either ensure a workable bug report gets filed or to make sure their solution gets submitted to CiviCRM, so that other WordPress-using sites can benefit.

Comment: I posted below the answer I discovered. Your [first linked article](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8475/the-contribution-payment-verification-page-has-lost-the-site-theme-styling) gave me an invaluable clue -- adding `&snippet=1` to the URL showed the form fields, so I knew it had something to do with the theme. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be my own fault... After I did the upgrade I did a little housecleaning. This WP site is only used for CiviCRM, so I figured I could delete the "Hello World" post. Nope -- that post is needed (or maybe just at least one post, I'm not certain). It was still in the trash, so I restored it, and the contribution pages started working again.

Props and an answer tick to Chris, as he set me down the right path of confirming that it was indeed something up with the theme.

Comment: Wow, that's a crazy fix, but I'm delighted you found it!